# All elements in array to lowercase - toLowerCase() method

Tags: java

I'm trying to turn all items in an array list in java to lowercase. Can anyone tell me what I did wrong?

```
    for (int i = 0; i <= books.size() - 1; i++) {
      books = books.toLowerCase();
      if (books.get(i).toString().contains(s)) {
        return true;
```

My program is basically a store that sells inventory. 
Each category of inventory is it's own array like:

```
books = new ArrayList<>();
```

I put requirements for sizes and such in a constructor

```
book_1 = new Book(300, 8, 500, true);
```

By itself it would print out something like:
Book with 300 pages, these dimensions, etc.

If the user wanted to search the item 'book' in the array I need it to return true and tell them there are results for that search. I'm trying to turn all strings in the array into lowercases so that capitals won't affect their search.

Comment: Perhaps if you show us your code.

Comment: You say that you want to change every element to lower case, but it appears that you are just trying to see if a given `String` is contained in the `List`, ignoring case. Could you clarify what this method is supposed to do?

Comment: yes, i added an update

Comment: `i <= books.size() - 1` is equivalent to `i < books.size()`.

Answer (score 1):

It *appears* that you want to see if a `String` representation of a `Book` is contained in the `List`, ignoring case.

```
books = books.toLowerCase();
```

doesn't work since the `ArrayList`class does not have a `toLowerCase` method; it is the `String` class which has it. You can use the built in method `equalsIgnoreCase()`:

```
for(int i =0; i < books.size(); i++) {
    if(books.get(i).toString().equalsIgnoreCase(s)) {
       return true;
    }
}
return false;
```

Or java 8+:

```
return books.stream().map(Book::toString).anyMatch(s::equalsIgnoreCase);
```

Or

```
return books.stream().anyMatch(book -> book.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(s));
```

Comment: hi! i got the error method equalsIgnoreCase in class java.lang.String cannot be applied to given types

Comment: @Tessa This compiles for me. Can you please provide an [MCVE]?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you've made a mistake and `books` is a list of strings. So in this case you can do something like this:

```
List<String> upperCaseBooks = books.stream().map(book -> book.toLowerCase()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: @GBlodgett it does seem like that, but the question specifically asks for turning all elements to lower case, even though it's most likely an XY problem.

Comment: @GBlodgett maybe you're right but OP says "I'm trying to turn all items in an array list in java to lowercase" so that's why I posted my answer. Anyway it's not easy to understand his question from OP's code;)